# Render Facebook like popup on left side

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I have my "Like" button on the bottom right of my page. When users click it, it is partially offscreen. Can I make the popup render to the left and above the button? Couldn't find it in the docs and there are no obvious options for that.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394078/facebook-like-send-button-flyout-direction

Answer (score 0):

Facebook moved the flyout into the like button `<iframe>` and therefore you cannot style it with CSS anymore, unfortunately.