# how to make Facebook like button's popup box to appear on the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

html to show like button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/TheGloopal/?fref=ts" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false" style='float:right;'></div>
```

[image]

BUt the popup when clicked on the fb like, appear on the right. But I want it to appear to the left as the button placed on the right.

[image]

I referred to this:[Facebook send button flyout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340230/facebook-send-button-flyout/6445134#6445134)

and tried  the following but doesn't work,

```
.fb_edge_widget_with_comment span.fb_edge_comment_widget {
   left: -45px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its in the html button code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/TheGloopal/?fref=ts" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false" style='float:right;'></div>
```

you need to change where it says `style='float:right;'` to `style='float:left;'`

Comment: I added this ( style='float:right;' ) actually to place the button on the right. I already tried ( style='float:left;' ). This only positions the like button on the left but popup still appears off the site.

Comment: try appending "position: absolute;" to the style

Comment: that doesn't make it appear to the left

Comment: Or is there a way to make it a popup that appears in the center to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/TheGloopal/?fref=ts" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false" style='float:left;'></div>
```

Comment: no need to change the CSS. Just needs to change the style inside the html tag.

Comment: @AmiteshKumar, the like button has to be on the right. I prefer the popup to appear to the left.

Comment: put that pop up div float left.

Comment: That's the thing, how do I do that, I'm not sure of the popup class.

Answer (score 0):

This solves the matter. I added below in the css

```
.fb_iframe_widget iframe {
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    background:#fff; /* in your case you may want to add a white background */
    transition: all .5s; /* completely optional, but adding a transition makes for a nice effect */
}
```